# GitHub API not providing my personal Organization

Tags: github, github-api

I need to fetch the repos with respect to organization. I have 2 repos in my github one is under a organization called 'A' and another is not under any organization.. When i try to fetch organization list using [user org list API](https://api.github.com/user/orgs). It gives me only the organization details which is 'A'. Not my personal organization is listing. How to get it?

I need to get the list of organization including my personal so that i can use the same to list repository which don't belong to any organization